# Referencing Abp framework in AbpZero project in solution doesnt work

Tags: visual-studio, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I dont want to use **Nugets**.

One project is utilizing a framework that i would like to keep under modification and construction so that i have the changes made one time throughout the entire solution. Both solutions (*Abp*:**ASP.Net Boilerplate** and *AbpZero*:**ASP.Net Boilerplate Zero**) are fine separately on their own. But the moment i create one solution and combine the projects, they just stop working, and it doesnt make enough sense. I've done everything from rewriting the `.csproj` files using text editors so that everything is uniform to a whole bunch of other time consuming tasks that hasnt worked for me. I've given up on trying to make things work for me in VS2015 (MS attempt at trying to encourage users to pay for VS2017-Pro) and settled for just using standard VS2017 (*Community* doesnt have the c# intellisense reference).

I just want one solution that combines the framework with the zero package that i paid for in one, so that i dont have to keep using nugets that arent compatible with my projects or designs.

**TLDR:**
Yellow references after combining projects when everything is supposed to work. What do i do to fix? Step-by-step, no generic responses like a forwarding to a MS wiki that doesnt solve problem.

Projects cant remain seperately because they point to `.Nugets`, and the problem is connecting the changes from the framework into the new solution.

---

[image: Separate Projects]
Separating projects are fine.
[image: Merged Projects]

But every time i combine, i always get some broken variation of these results. Either the nugets dont load properly for the rest, or specifically the `abp` framework doesnt combine properly with the project solution. All the information matches up otherwise (framework, compatibility, references, etc...).

Second image left project nugets won't load when project is built, and the references arent working in the code. If i use the `peek/go to definition` or `find all references` it either points back to itself or gives error. This whole project is becoming a major waste of time and money...

Comment: Why do you need to modify the framework?

Comment: So that it can function for my purposes, also there are modifications that i *need* to make to it. Also, with that question being asked, why open-source the framework if you're not supposed to modify it?